# How to get a text inside an input tag with a hidden type

Tags: python, selenium

I want to retrieve the text "22/22" from the following html code :

```html
<td style="font-size:9pt;">
    <input type="text" name="semaine.journees[3].plageHoraires[0].capacite" maxlength="3" size="2" value="22" onfocus="ChampSel=3" id="cap3" style="width:20px">
    <input type="hidden" name="capaciteMin" value="22">22/22
</td>
```

In Python with the Selenium library, I wrote the following code but the console displays nothing :

```python
inputValue = browser.find_element_by_id("cap" + str(count)).get_attribute('value')
elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value=" + inputValue+"]").get_attribute("textContent")
print(elements)
```

I saw that the type of the input tag in question was equal to hidden. Would you have a solution for me, please?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to extract text from `input` node while `input` nodes cannot contain any text. You need to select parent `td` node. Try

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[input[@value='{}']]".format(inputValue)).get_attribute("textContent").strip()
```